# Given IP address, but can only ping sometimes

Tags: networking, firewall, dhcp, wifi

I have a debian server that acts as a wifi router and DHCP and FTP server.

I want to connect to this server using a Canon Wireless File Transmitter.

I can connect and receive an IP address. I can verify this in syslog:

```
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:00:85:ff:81:cc IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:00:85:ff:81:cc IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:00:85:ff:81:cc RADIUS: starting accounting session 501D7991-00000002
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.10.0.24 to 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.10.0.24 to 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.0.24 (10.10.0.1) from 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.10.0.24 to 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.0.24 (10.10.0.1) from 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
Aug  4 21:37:02 box-3 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.10.0.24 to 00:00:85:ff:81:cc via wlan0
```

However, the File Transmitter seems to have problems discovering or connecting to the FTP server.

When I try pinging the IP address I sometimes can reach the file transmitter, and after that the connection is open and the file transmitter can reach the FTP server.

But this does not always work.

I tried tcpdumping all the traffic on my wlan0 device, but all I got was some ARP requests.

What are some ways I can debug this?

Comment: Do you get problems throughout the subnet 10.10.0.* or literally just trying to get to this machine?

Comment: Well I can ping my laptop that is connected to the router and I can access the FTP server from my laptop. It just seems to be the file transmitter that is having problems.